# Getting Primary HDD serial on OSx using terminal

Tags: java, macos, hardware, hard-drive, serial-number

Ok, so I think the title of this question pretty much sums it up.

I would to know of a way to obtain the serial number of the HDD  that the operating system is installed on, in OSx without having Admin privileges. Preferably, I would like to do this using Terminal because I need to use the serial in my Java application and I doubt Java has the capabilities to obtain the information itself.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know, hopefully someone else does, if not you might want to try here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @rooftop Oh, Thanks for that. Personally, I thought this question was more appropriate here. Would you mind upvoting my question for me?

Comment: I don't have any problem with the question being here, just wasn't sure if you were aware of the other site.

Comment: @rooftop I know you weren't telling me to move it, I was just saying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/usr/sbin/diskutil info / | /usr/bin/awk '$0 ~ /UUID/ { print $3 }'
```

That should give you the serial of the drive mounted at root.

Comment: Thanks but nothing is being outputted when I type that in the Terminal?

Comment: What if you just type `/usr/sbin/diskutil info /` ?

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply. If I type `/usr/sbin/diskutil info/` it says diskutil did not recognize verb "info/"... But if I take off the last `/` it just comes up with the usage. so if I type `usr/sbin/diskutil info | /usr/bin/awk '$0 ~ /UUID/ { print $3 }'` it still doesn't return anything!

Comment: Never mind, it looks like I've solved the problem... You have to specify the volume id, ie `diskutil info /dev/disk0s2` the you want (and can get) the UUID for. And I've just found out that to get the ID of my desired volume I can use `df -h` in the Terminal!